# Harpy stalemate

Tags: werewolv.es

What happens when you have, say 5 village members with no killing or blocking or vote manipulation capabilities and 4 coven members where one is a harpy? Given the coven and village both play optimally, there will never be a winner? By silencing one village member, there will only be 4 valid coven votes and 4 valid village votes, but the number of people means that parity will never be achieved, if the village doesn't mislynch.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is correct in that this will result in a perpetual stalemate situation and would require manual moderator intervention to come in and end the game.

Although this situation is an incredible edge case, your question had made me think that perhaps I should add a check to the game that if there hasn't been a death in X number of nights, the game ends in a draw.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is in the game you are speaking about, but while playing the boardgame Werewolves that this seem to be based on, there is usually a captain/mayor that is appointed at the beginning of the game, and that is transfered when the captain/mayor meets with his grim fate. (Usually the last action of a mayor is naming their successor)

That role usually breaks ties, because his vote counts to 1.5 instead of 1.

So if that role is in the game, there is no chance of tie because there is always the mayor to break them.